# MicroPython machine UART instantiation throws error

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, uart, micropython

I'm trying to achieve a serial communication between RPI Pico W and an ESP8266 board. I saw that this is easy using the UART class from the machine module but it throws and error (ValueError: expecting a Pin) but I haven't found anything about this in the documentation.

Line of code in quesion is:

`uart = machine.UART(1, baudrate=9600, tx=0, rx=1)`

This is the way to instantiate an uart object, at least that's what I found on some tutorials and various GitHub repos.

I tried using Pin but I didn't get far.

```
tx_pin = machine.Pin(0)
rx_pin = machine.Pin(1)
uart = machine.UART(0, 9600, tx_pin, rx_pin)
```

Writing it like this, I get an error TypeError: can't convert Pin to int

I also tried examples from [this](https://stackoverflow.com) question but they don't work for me. Looks like there was an update in the library but not in the documentation.

I am quite new to python so I might be using this wrong but that's why I'm here. Can you suggest any other way to achieve serial comms if there is no fix for this?

Comment: `tx=` and `rx=` are keyword-only parameters for this class.  You're passing your pins as the `bits` and `parity` parameters instead.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: `tx_pin = machine.Pin(0)
rx_pin = machine.Pin(1)
uart = machine.UART(0, 9600, 8, None, tx_pin, rx_pin)`? Because I still get the same TypeError.

Comment: You have to specify the pins with keyword arguments `tx=` and `rx=`, just like in the line of code you quoted.

Comment: Yep I just realised it and fiexd it. Thank you for you help :)